# Ran "chkdsk /r /f /x" on c drive

Tags: windows-8, chkdsk, filesystem-corruption

So I used the /x flag accidentally with dskchk on drive c(my os drive). I don't know why, guess it slipped my brain or something. Anyway the question is:

Should I do anything to stop the currently running action, as I heard it could cause file corruption. Or should I just let it complete? Also if it causes corruption what should I do?

I would greatly appreciate answers, as I am panicking quite a bit now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From `chkdsk /?`:

> /X - Forces the volume to dismount first if necessary.
>   All opened handles to the volume would then be invalid
>   (implies /F).

It's just the switch to force a dismount, instead of stopping to ask if you want to dismount the drive before running the disk scan (to ensure and currently open handles/files on it are closed before scanning).

No need to panic.

Answer (score 1):

My experience on attempting to chkdsk the OS volume while running Windows has always caused Windows to indicate that the chkdsk will occur on the next reboot.